# encode download url

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Download.php

```
$dl_file = $_GET['download_file'];
```

I don't want to directly show download url every time i point arrow to download button, I am using Codeigniter. How do I encode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base 64 will not work in all the cases because it uses characters that are not transferable thru the browser.

You should use it as follow:

```
href="http://mywebsite/index.php/files/download?download_file=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode($ph['FileName']));?>"
```

And decode it in download.php

```
$dl_file = base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['download_file']));
```

Comment: base64 encoding puts == sign in encoded value and it is not permitted by default in URL. so you should go to **application/config/config.php**
and change the following value.
`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=';`

The equal sign at last is added by me, but it won't be there by default.

Comment: You can use Md5 but then there will be different technique to compare file name in download.php file. Because md5 can not be decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal what you can do is:

encode your url

```
href="http://mywebsite/index.php/files/download?download_file=<?php echo base64_encode($ph['FileName']);?>"
```

And decode it in download.php

```
$dl_file = base64_decode($_GET['download_file']);
```

Comment: base64 encoding puts == sign in encoded value and it is not permitted by default in URL. so you should go to **application/config/config.php**
and change the following value.
`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=';`

The equal sign at last is added by me, but it won't be there by default.